# Qt и http-прокси

Tags: сеть, qt, c++, proxy

Задаю для QNetworkManager прокси:

```
QString name = ui->proxyAddressLineEdit->text();
quint16 port = ui->proxyPortSpinBox->value();
QString user = ui->proxyUserLineEdit->text();
QString pass = ui->proxyPasswordLineEdit->text();
proxy.setHostName(name);
proxy.setPort(port);
proxy.setUser(user);
proxy.setPassword(pass);
manager->setProxy(proxy);
connect(manager,                      SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),
        this,                         SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));
```

Получаю страницу:

```
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(urlString)));
```

Вопрос! Как узнать, было ли успешно установлено соединение с прокси? Если его не было, страницы не грузятся, как и надо, но как это проверить программно?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать `reply` и проверять его через `isReadable()`

```
            if (!reply->isReadable())
            return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто отправляете HTTP-запрос на какой-нибудь сайт, который, как известно заранее, доступен. Например поисковик (гугло-яндекс). А затем читаете ответ: если 200 OK, то норма, работает.

Answer (score 0):

Получили страницу, значит работает, не получили, значит не работает. Если получили ответ "страница не существует", значит не найдена страница или проблема блокировки сайта на прокси, но эту страницу уже выдаст прокси, а значит страница получена будет. Смысла нет тестировать на адресе определенного сайта типа гугл или яндекс, может у фирмы будет доступ через прокси только к внутренним сайтам, но не к внешним и т.п. ситуации. Нужно вести анализ приходящего ответа на "запрос" менеджера.